# An outerplanar G graph such that $G+k_1$ is not planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

An outerplanar graph is an undirected graph that can be drawn in the plane without crossings in such a way that all of the vertices belong to the unbounded face of the drawing. That is, no vertex is totally surrounded by edges. Alternatively, a graph G is outerplanar if the graph formed from G by adding a new vertex, with edges connecting it to all the other vertices, is a planar graph.

The join $G=G_1+G_2$ of graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ with disjoint point sets $V_1$ and $V_2$ and edge sets  $X_1$ and $X_2$ is the graph union $G_1$ union $G_2$ together with all the edges joining $V_1$ and $V_2$.

Does it exist An outerplanar $G$ graph such that $G+ k_1$ is not planar graph? where $k_1$ is a vertex.
can you help me?

Comment: What is definition of $k1$?

Comment: Isn't $G+k_1$ planar when $G$ is outerplanar, precisely because of the sentence *"Alternatively, a graph G is outerplanar if the graph formed from G by adding a new vertex, with edges connecting it to all the other vertices, is a planar graph."*?

Comment: I agree with that, **iff** $k_1$ is really supposed to mean the regular graph on one vertex (aka graph with a single vertex and no edges)

Comment: A graph is outerplanar if and only if it does not contain $K_4$ or $K_{2,3}$ as minor.